# Why doesn't my owned one-to-many relationship get persisted to the GAE datastore?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo, datanucleus

I have two classes defined and mapped to the GAE datastore - a `Person` class and a `LocationStamp` class, which represents a single latitude/longitude combination along with a timestamp. There is an owned one-to-many mapping between `Person` and `LocationStamp`, implemented on similar lines as [a forum post on one-to-many relationships](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-java/VMg9xiQv1jM).

In my DAO for `Person`, I have the following method:

```
   public LocationStamp addLocationStampForCurrentUser(LocationStamp ls)
   {
      PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();

      Person p = getProfileForCurrentUser();
      p.getLocationStamps().add(ls);

      pm.currentTransaction().begin();
      try {
         pm.makePersistent(p);
         pm.currentTransaction().commit();
         return ls;
      } finally {
         if (pm.currentTransaction().isActive()) {
            pm.currentTransaction().rollback();
         }
         pm.close();
      }
   }
```

When I try using this method to add an entry to the object's collection of `LocationStamp` entities, **the relationship does not get persisted**. A later query for the relevant `Person` object returns the correct object with email address, but the `locationStamps` list is empty. Moreover, the Data Viewer for the App Engine server does not show any `LocationStamp` entities (and there isn't any column shown for `locationStamps` in the table for `Person`.

I followed the instructions in the forum post carefully, but I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

Here are my entities:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
public class Person
{

   @PrimaryKey
   @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
   private Key key;

   @Persistent
   private String emailAddress;

   @Persistent
   private String name;

   @Persistent(mappedBy = "person")
   @Element(dependent = "true")
   @Order(extensions = @Extension(vendorName = "datanucleus", key = "list-ordering", value = "timestamp desc"))
   private final List<LocationStamp> locationStamps = new ArrayList<LocationStamp>();

   // ... getters and setters ...
}
```

and

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
public class LocationStamp
{

   @PrimaryKey
   @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
   private Key key;

   @Persistent
   private double latitude;

   @Persistent
   private double longitude;

   @Persistent
   private Date timestamp;

   @Persistent
   private boolean automatic;

   @Persistent
   private Person person;

   // ... getters and setters ...
}
```

Since they're used in the above code, here are the definitions for a couple of other methods:

```
   public Person getProfileForCurrentUser()
   {
      PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();
      try {
         Key k = getKeyForEmailAddress(getCurrentUserEmail());
         return pm.getObjectById(Person.class, k);
      } catch (JDOObjectNotFoundException e) {
         // Create a new profile if the new one isn't found
         return updateProfileForCurrentUser(new Person());
      } finally {
         pm.close();
      }
   }

   public Person updateProfileForCurrentUser(Person p)
   {
      p.setEmailAddress(getCurrentUserEmail());
      return update(p);
   }

   public Person update(Person p)
   {
      PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();
      try {
         pm.currentTransaction().begin();
         Key k = getKeyForEmailAddress(p.getEmailAddress());
         p.setKey(k);
         pm.makePersistent(p);
         pm.currentTransaction().commit();
         return p;
      } finally {
         if (pm.currentTransaction().isActive()) {
            pm.currentTransaction().rollback();
         }
         pm.close();
      }
   }

   private Key getKeyForEmailAddress(String emailAddress)
   {
      return KeyFactory.createKey(Person.class.getSimpleName(), emailAddress);
   }

   private static PersistenceManager getPersistenceManager()
   {
      // PMF is a singleton class that returns an instance of PersistenceManagerFactory
      return PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a List in a Persistence object, the load of the list are a lazy operation. So if you close the `PersistenceManager` before load the list, the list will be not loaded.

Try using:

```
public Person getProfileForCurrentUser()
{
    PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        Key k = getKeyForEmailAddress(getCurrentUserEmail());
        Person p = pm.getObjectById(Person.class, k);
        p.getLocationStamps().size();
        return p;
    } catch (JDOObjectNotFoundException e) {
        // Create a new profile if the new one isn't found
        return updateProfileForCurrentUser(new Person());
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. I thought I got rid of all the lazy loading issues when I followed the forum post's instructions, but I clearly needed to explicitly load the list too.